# IOS App and Background

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have a music signal processor app I want to publish and it needs to run in the back ground. I used to Info-plist to do so with UIBackgroundModes. It runs on IOS7 or less, and the problem I am having is once the phone locks and the app goes into the background I can't get it to come out of the background and its keeps running with the red banner at the top. Some of this I have learned as I go, but I have noticed some run on a timer, but I want mine, since its a music processor to keep going until the phone either unlocks or whatever interrupted it stops.

The app is basically a stomp box used with iRig. If that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify about what you mean when the phone locks, the app goes into the background and yo can't get it to come out of the background? Are you saying like the app is playing music while the app is locked?

Comment: When the app is running and the phone goes to sleep or on my phone locks because I have a password on it. When this happens I want the audio to keep playing, so I modified the plist and when the phone sleeps/locks it keeps playing audio but  I can't get back to the app, the app is listed as running at the top of the phone but clicking on it(the banner showing its running) takes me no where and the only way I can shut off my app is to re-boot the device. Does this make sense?

Comment: @DixonSteel yea it makes more sense now, or I could just be stupid that I didn't understand your first question. I don't know exactly how to fix your problem but the issue is somewhere in the AppDelegate.m file. I know that whenever you launch or open the app can be configured in the AppDelegate.m, you might want to look there.

Comment: Thanks, I may try and set the background from the Xcode IDE and not the plist. It may do the same thing, but I will try. I really have no idea on this one and it is the last thing I have to do before I try to submit.